# How to replace multiple variable from file.txt

Tags: node.js, replace, node.js-fs

Inside file form.txt

> Name : $name
>
> Gender : $gender
>
> Age : $age

is my code to replace variable in form.txt

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

var rForm = await fs.readFile(__dirname + '/form.txt', 'utf8');

var name = 'maman';
var gender = 'male';
var age = 10;

rForm.replace('$name', name);
rForm.replace('$gender', gender);
rForm.replace('$age', age);

console.log(rForm);
```

and is my result from my code

> Name : $name
>
> Gender : $gender
>
> Age : $age

There is noting changed. The result I wanted is

> Name: maman
>
> Gender: male
>
> Age: 10

How to change multiple variable in this case ??

I try this

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

var rForm = await fs.readFile(__dirname + '/form.txt', 'utf8');

var name = 'maman';
var gender = 'male';
var age = 10;

var nm = rForm.replace('$name', name);
var gn = rForm.replace('$gender', gender);
var ag = rForm.replace('$age', age);

console.log(nm);
console.log(gn);
console.log(ag);`
```

and the result is

> Name : maman
>
> Gender : $gender
>
> Age : $age
>
> Name : $name
>
> Gender : male
>
> Age : $age
>
> Name : $name
>
> Gender : $gender
>
> Age : 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method returns a new string with one, some, or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

```js
rForm = rForm.replace('$name', name)
             .replace('$gender', gender)
             .replace('$age', age);

console.log(rForm);
```

or

```js
rForm = rForm.replace('$name', name);
rForm = rForm.replace('$gender', gender);
rForm = rForm.replace('$age', age);

console.log(rForm);
```

Comment: thankyou the first explanation can be used :)